# Where do I store the Notes if I want an "Add Note" function in my app

Tags: iphone

I want to add a simple note to my app. After searching, I found that I need: a tableView and the active Note's view "please tell me if I'm missing some thing".

What I couldn't find is How and Where to store the notes and how to retrieve it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For storing simple objects like strings for notes, take a look at [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:@"hello" forKey:@"key"]; // Store value.

NSString *note = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"]; // Retrieve value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Core data provides a good mechanism for persisting data that is more complex. Check out the guide here: [Core Data.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)